# I need Google Spreadsheet help. To call multipule cells from sheet one to another sheet in the same workbook, based on a cell marked on sheet1

Tags: google-sheets

If you understand the title or not, then the only thing I can give you to explain my need is a picture.

[image]

This should help, but I could answer any questions you have to help me with my needs. I could likely script this, I just am not sure how to, and would love some ideas.

Comment: If you're looking to share your picture, just upload it somewhere like [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/) and put the link in your post.

Comment: If you would like to refer to the cell A1 in Sheet1 from Sheet2, just use **=Sheet1!A1**

Comment: Yes that's the simple way and I know that much. Please see the picture, this is a little more advanced than that.

Comment: Okay I just spoke with someone that told me this would be a sql or syntax query, and would likely cause problems on the subsequent sheets. So good idea, just not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know the exact answer for this problem, but I would use a workaround here:

In the "Auto Trader" sheet (cell A3) I would use the FILTER function as follows:

=FILTER(Dealers!A:D;Dealers!E:E="X")

This will produce all the lines from "Dealers" worksheet which matches the criteria that in the appropriate AutoTrader column it has an "X".

Unfortunately, this is a workaround, since you have to do this for all worksheets, modifying the formula accordingly. (like for the next - Cars.com - worksheet: =FILTER(Dealers!A:D;Dealers!F:F="X")

Hope it helped anyway.

Comment: ZOLLEY you are a f-ing genius. That is exactly what I was looking for. Its easy to copy to the subsequent sheets. Now the task will be to lock the rows in the subsequent sheets together (as they have passwords and ID's for the specific dealers) so if the Dealers sheet is filtered, the subsequent sheets filter as well, but keep the ID's and Pass's assigned to the correct dealer...

Comment: Can you clarify this locking business a bit more? I don't get it. :) But glad to help a bit anyway.

Comment: Once the autotrader page is populated from the Dealers page with the formula you shared, I am going to add the passwords and ID's to that dealers row in the following columns. If the filter on the Dealers sheet changes, it changes the order of the dealers on the autotrader page, but the passwords and ID's stay on the same row as I originally assigned them; they don't move with the dealer when it changes rows. Is there a way to keep them together?

Comment: Yeah, okay - that's a valid problem unfortunately. I have encountered with it several times, so if I do something like that I ensure that every raw data is collected on one data page (in this case that would be the Dealers page) - even if that means that worksheet looks a bit messy. But later on it pays out, because on the following sheets you will only have automatically generated (filtered) data. Or at least that would be the goal. So the question is: Can't you add an ID and pass globally on the Dealers page? Or is it necessary to be unique for every worksheet?

Comment: they must be unique on the autotrader page. So adding any new dealers must be added to the bottom of the list on the Dealers page. Thank you Zolley

Comment: well, that's the awkward part. As I said, it's a workaround, this is one of its limitations. Hope you can still use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Query Language 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Or make a Google Script to copy data on your "auto trader" sheet.